# MySQL to Oracle Migration

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

I want to port my database from MySQL to Oracle 12c. What is the best way to do that?

My project is written in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best way to start with is Oracle's utility which you can found [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/mysql-093223.html).

But then you also need to verify data types of your fields because it creates problem with some complex data types like `BLOB` etc

Comment: how to check all data types that they are converted correct?

Comment: There will be a transaction rollback exception while inserting records in that particular table.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has provide the documentation for migration.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/mysql-093223.html

For migrating application, If you are using any ORM then you have start working on the configurations first.

If your application has a lot of SQLs/procedures then you need help from your DBA team. They can migrate data as well as procedures etc.